# printing of xml

Tags: php, xml

I want to print the array into xml format but i am unable to print it.
Here is the code

```
if(!empty($recordsArray)){
print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n>");
print("<joblist>\n");   
foreach ($recordsArray as $data){
```

print("".$data['user_id']."".$data['$task_id']."\n");

```
}
print("</joblist>\n");

} 
}
```

even i am unable to see

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n>
```

when i am doing view source its showing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<joblist> 
<job><id>123</id><taskid>14</taskid></job> 
</joblist>
```

now what to be done to display on the web page

Comment: We won't just write a program for you, here. Can you be more specific about the part that's giving you trouble?

Comment: maybe view source?  If you are outputting xml to the browser it won't display the processing instruction (just like outputting <html> doesn't cause <html> to be displayed in the browser window, but view source shows it)

Comment: Are you *sure* that `$recordsArray` is not empty?

Comment: @ Demian Brecht i have tried with print_r() and its giving me the record

Comment: Did you mean to have the last bracket? It is not matched by another if that's all your code. Maybe your setup is not configured to report errors and you have an error?

Comment: In the view source i am getting the result now what to be done to display on the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two problems:

1. I don't think `print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n>");` will generate valid xml, shouldn´t it be:

   `print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n");`
2. I don´t think `print("<job><id>$data[$user_id]</id><taskid>$data[$task_id]</taskid></job>\n");` is going to work, try something like:

   `print("<job><id>".$data[$user_id]."</id><taskid>".$data[$task_id]."</taskid></job>\n");`

Comment: i have given a try but  no luck .

Comment: Thanks its solve one problem but its only visible in the view source

Comment: @user667340 You will need to combine my answer with @brettz9's answer.

Comment: Did it mean i have to set 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
     <head>
 
   </head>  on the top of the page

Comment: @user667340 I don´t understand, do you want to output xml to the browser or do you want to echo your xml in a section on an html page?

Comment: i want to display on the web page . I mean if i put this page.php?identifier=123 in the url it should show me the reult in the xml format on the web page

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be viewed in the browser, instead of what is most likely your server's default, "text/html", you need to serve the file as "text/xml" or "application/xml".

You might not be able to see the tags because they are treated as bogus HTML (though they are no doubt in the source code if you view source)--though admittedly you should see any text inside the elements.

In any case, you will want to create a header (before you do any printing, including printing whitespace) anyways, to ensure it is displayed and treated as XML by the user's browser, by adding:

```
header('Content-type:application/xml;charset=utf8');
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run print_r($recordsArray)?  It is possible that it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm debugging and need to write xml to a browser I usually put it in a `<textarea>`.  You need to print the results into a container that will display html tokens like < and > literally, or go through your string and convert them all to entities.